# Unable to create or edit menus

Tags: menus, media-library

I'm running 3.4.2 on Ubuntu. I'm unable to make any changes to menus at all. Also I'm unable to upload anything (flash or browser uploader) to the media library. However plugins have no problem adding things to the library. When I try to make a change I get page not found.

I have my memory limit set at 128MB in php.ini and wp-config.php. I've done all the basic troubleshooting on the wordpress wiki. Disabled all my plugins, switched themes, even ran *aptitude reinstall wordpress* just to make sure all the core files weren't damaged.

This is my debug.log

```
[21-Nov-2012 02:37:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  wp_enqueue_script was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the <code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>, <code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>, or <code>init</code> hooks. Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2758
[21-Nov-2012 02:37:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  wp_enqueue_style was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the <code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>, <code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>, or <code>init</code> hooks. Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2758
[21-Nov-2012 02:37:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/update.php on line 92
```

I'm managed to stump my self here. I've done everything short of re-installing the entire site.

Comment: What happens if you set the PHP memory limit to 256M instead of 128M?

Comment: HOLY CRAP THAT WORKED!? Thank you Chip!

Comment: Oh, well great! I've just added that as an answer, then; with some additional information.

Answer (score 1):

> I have my memory limit set at 128MB in php.ini and wp-config.php. There is [an implicit minimum requirement](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/wordpress-3-0-memory-requirements-256-mb/) for the WP Admin to be able to use 256M.

Try setting your PHP memory limit to **256M** instead of 128M.

Also, be sure you have `WP_DEBUG` set to `true` in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Which will likely reveal an exhausted-memory fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

backup your wp-config.php, delete the original and run your yoursite/wp-admin again, filling all the fields back.... hope it works. if not, wich theme are you using?

Comment: Explain **why** that could solve the problem.